# How to align text and image in xslt with css

Tags: css, image, text

Hi I have an xml file in wich I put some image in this way: `<pb facs="ciao.jpg">`.
Then I have an xsl file where i put a Java script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleSize(img){
        if (parseInt(img.style.width) !=220){
            img.style.width='220px';
        }
        else {
            img.style.width = '90%';
        }
    }

    function showHideNote(noteId){
        var note = document.getElementById(noteId);
        if (note.className == 'hiddenNote') {
            note.className='showingNote';
        }
        else {
            note.className='hiddenNote';
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and it makes a little image where I can click and all the text under.
So the problem is that I would like to have a bigger image on the left and the text related on the right. Any suggestion?

Comment: Float the image, I think. Can you show the relevant part of the resulting HTML output?

Comment: You mean the code?<body>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#chapter_1">Capitulo primeyro</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      
      
      
      
     
      
      
      
      
      <div>
         
         <h1 style="text-align:center" id="chapter_1">Capitulo primeyro</h1>
         
         
         
         <img src="folio16r.jpg" style="width: 120px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="toggleSize(this)" alt="page image from manuscript" />
         
         
         
         
         <p style="text-align:justify; font-family:garamond"> dddd
         </p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `float: left` to the style for the image.

```
<div>
<h1 style="text-align:center" id="chapter_1">Capitulo primeyro</h1>
<img src="folio16r.jpg" style="width: 120px; cursor: pointer; float: left"
  onclick="toggleSize(this)" alt="page image from manuscript">
<p style="text-align:justify; font-family:garamond"> dddd </p>
</div>
```

By the way, the html you posted in the comment is not the same as the original question (the question has `ciao.jpg` for the picture, while the HTML has `folio16r.jpg`. And I'm not sure how and where you're appying the style. So I hope you can make this work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But the image is still very little. Where do I have to work if I want the image bigger?

Comment: How big do you want the image? As big as it is by itself? In that case, remove the `width: 120px` constraint from the style. Also, I'm not sure what the `toggleSize` function is and when it is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But because I am working on an xsl file is not possile to write this rule in this one? Otherwise do I  have to rewrite  the rule every time I produce a new html?

Comment: Well, you haven't posted all of the XML (only a single start tag in fact) and nothing of the XSLT, so I can only guess, but like I said, I don't know where the style actually comes from, at which point it gets inserted in the HTML stream. You can of course, apply any style in the usual way: make a CSS file. Generate a `<link>` in the XSLT, give the img a `class`... Other than that, I can't really help you, as IO don't know how large the images are, how large they need to be on the screen, and what the `toggleSize` function does...

Comment: You are right. So I was able now to put the image on the left and the text on the right, due to xslt. And that's a very good thing. Now I am working on width to resize them. Originally they are 1134 px for 930px...

Comment: I am tryibg to modify the number in my style in css in xslt:<style type="text/css">img {float:left;width: 50%;
                        height: 34%;margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
                        }            
                        p {
                        text-align: justify;
                        font-size: big;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 304;
                        }
                        </style> but for some reason the image is always little, I can just modify the heigh and not the width.

Comment: Not sure. Maybe 50% of the available width is too small for the img? I can't tell from here. What I can tell is that you have an error in the style for the `p`: `big` is not a correct font size. You probably want `large`. and `304` is not a correct height. It should have a unit, for instance `304px` if you mean 304 pixels.